# 'AuthenticationManager' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I have the following code to connect to SharePoint using clientID and ClientSecret:-

```
string siteUrl = "https://****l.sharepoint.com/sites/DocumentApprovalProcess/";
string clientId = "***";
string clientSecret = "**";

using (var context = new AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
```

but i am getting this error:-

```
'AuthenticationManager' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you installed Office Dev PnP:https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline

You could refer to this article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connect-to-sharepoint-online-site-with-app-only-authentication/

```
using OfficeDevPnP.Core;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

    string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/demo";  
    using (var cc = new AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, "[Your Client ID]", "[Your Client Secret]"))  
    {  
        cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);  
        cc.ExecuteQuery();  
        Console.WriteLine(cc.Web.Title);  
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem is a ambiguity between system.net and PnP.Framework

```
    string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/demo";  
    using (var cc = new PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, "[Your Client ID]", "[Your Client Secret]"))  
    {  
        cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);  
        cc.ExecuteQuery();  
        Console.WriteLine(cc.Web.Title);  
    };
```